# WordPress Settings API unable to save settings

Tags: php, settings-api

So I can't seem to get the Settings API to save a field properly, I feel like I've followed ever single step, but I'm having no luck, so I wanted to reach out and see if someone might be able to spot anything that I might be doing wrong.

Whenever I input something in the field and I click on "Save Settings", it just refreshes and nothing get written to the database nor does it input anything into the field.

**This is how the form looks on the backend**:
[image]

**This the output of the form**:
[image]

**This is the code**:

```
class FH_Pardot_Settings
{
    private static string $option_group = 'pardot_settings';
    private static string $page = 'pardot';

    /**
     * Fields for Settings API
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private static array $fields = [
        'client_id' => '',
        'submit' => ''
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (is_admin()) {
            add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'admin_init']);
            add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'admin_menu']);
        }
    }

    public function admin_menu()
    {
        $title = __('Pardot', 'pardot');
        add_options_page(
                $title,
                $title,
                'manage_options',
                self::$page,
                [$this, 'settings_page']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register API Credentials Settings
     */
    public function admin_init(): void
    {
        self::$fields = [
            'client_id' => [__('Consumer Key', 'pardot'), ''],
            'submit' => '',
        ];
        register_setting(
                self::$option_group,
                self::$option_group,
        );
        add_settings_section(
                self::$option_group,
                __('Pardot Settings', 'pardot'),
                [$this, 'user_account_section'],
                self::$page
        );

        foreach (self::$fields as $name => $array) {
            $title = $array[0] ?? null;
            $class = $array[1] ?? null;
            add_settings_field(
                    $name,
                    $title,
                    [$this, "{$name}_field"],
                    self::$page,
                    self::$option_group,
                    $class
            );
        }
    }

    public function user_account_section(): void
    {
        $msg = __('Use the below section to input settings for the Pardot API', 'pardot');
        echo "<span id=\"instructions\">{$msg}</span>";
    }

    public function settings_page()
    {
        $html = <<<HTML
                <form action="options.php" method="post">
                HTML;
        echo $html;

        settings_fields(self::$option_group);
        do_settings_sections(self::$page);

        echo "</form>";
    }

    private function get_html_name($field_name)
    {
        return self::$option_group . "[{$field_name}]";
    }

    public function client_id_field()
    {
        $client_id = get_option('pardot_client_id');
        $html_name = $this->get_html_name('pardot_client_id');
        $msg = __('Input the consumer key', 'pardot');
        $html = <<<HTML
                <div id="client-id-wrap">
                    <input type="text" size="30" id="pardot_client_id" name="pardot_client_id" value="{$client_id}" />
                    <p>{$msg}</p>
                </div>
                HTML;
        echo $html;
    }

    public function submit_field()
    {
        $value = __('Save Settings', 'pardot');
        $html = <<<HTML
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" name="save" value="{$value}" />
                HTML;
        echo $html;
    }
}

new FH_Pardot_Settings();
```

Comment: Noting that in the heredocs in `submit_field`, `get_html_name`, `user_account_section ` and `client_id_field` there's no escaping which is a big security concern. Consider moving away from heredocs and using `esc_attr`, `esc_html` and `wp_kses_post` to escape the variables so that they're output safely

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell, I don't usually do that, but thanks for explaining the reasoning behind that, I will go back and make udates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<input>` generated by your `client_id_field()` function is using the wrong `name` which is `pardot_client_id`, and by "wrong", I mean there's no **database** option registered with that name and the one you've registered is named `pardot_settings`.

- The database option is the *second parameter* for [`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/).
- And it should be used in the `name` attribute of form fields like `<input>` and `<select>`, e.g. `<input name="DATABASE OPTION NAME">`.

So looking at your class, you should have used `<input type="text" size="30" id="pardot_client_id" name="{$html_name}" value="{$client_id}" />` there.

And then get the saved option like so:

```php
// Get all settings in the option array.
$options = (array) get_option( self::$option_group );

// Get the pardot_client_id setting.
$client_id = $options['pardot_client_id'] ?? '';
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Sally, that worked perfectly! I can't believe I didn't catch that. The options are now saved and retrieved.